# How do I put new clips on my ford truck door to the interior door panel it tight?

Tags: ford, door, truck, clips

My Ford truck door has needed new clips on it for months. I got new ones, but I don't want to mess up the door panel when I go to replace them.

Any suggestions or experience to help?
Thanx, Amber

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you show us pictures of the clips you are replacing and exactly where they are supposed to go? This would help us know we are thinking of what you are trying to describe.